# Issue when switching icons on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm trying to switch an font-awesome icon (located at a card-header with a collapsible card-body) when clicking on it. But, when I click the button, the card-body below doesn't collapse, and I get an error on my Browser Console.

Error:

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null
at a.t._getParent (collapse.js:300)
at new a (collapse.js:88)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:345)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.a._jQueryInterface [as collapse] (collapse.js:331)
at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:378)
at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLElement.<anonymous> (collapse.js:374)
```

The collapse.js:

```
const children = [].slice.call(parent.querySelectorAll(selector))
      $(children).each((i, element) => {
        this._addAriaAndCollapsedClass(
          Collapse._getTargetFromElement(element),
          [element]
        )
      })
```

My header.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Web System</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich|Raleway|Rosario" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
```

My script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("i.fas, fa-plus").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-plus fa-minus");
    });
});
```

My HTML structure:

```
<div class="col-8">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fas fa-plus float-right" id="cardOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseFirst" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseFirst"></i>
                Change image
        </div>
        <div id="collapseFirst" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="cardOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
                <form action="menus.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <input type="file" name="customAvatar" required>
                    <input type="submit" value="Salvar">
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry if I commited some mistakes on the question, pretty new in here ;)

Comment: The problem is not evident from the code that you've posted. The error message mentions a call to `querySelectorAll` but that doesn't appear anywhere in the JS you've posted.

Comment: Sorry, just edited with the proper code block, thanks for the advice!